# .load vs .on("load")

Tags: jquery

i am loading a php page inside a div that takes a posted variable to display the proper content. it works using this:

```
$(".mainArea").load("page.php", {'folder': 'a'}).fadeIn(); 
//passes vars, but all my jquery event handlers no longer work
```

the problem is that after i dynamically load this content - i cant get my event handlers to work. so i thought the solution would be this:

```
$(".mainArea").on("load", "page.php", {'folder': 'a'}).fadeIn(); 
// all event handlers still work - but the variables do not get posted...
```

any ideas on how i can combine these two or get the later to actually pass variables?

Comment: I think load() loads and on("load") registers an event handler.

Comment: These are two completely different issues. From [the jQuery API on .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/): *Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. ... Note: The event handling suite also has a method named .load(). jQuery determines which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it.* I can't see how moving the data fetching part of `load` into  `on` which exclusively deals with event listening would make any sense at all.

Comment: that makes sense that they are not the same thing... i am guessing that i need to use $(".mainArea").load("page.php", {'folder': 'a'}).fadeIn(); to load the content in. i just need to have all the events that i have set up continue to work. so the events are bind to elements inside the dynamically loaded content...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) loads data from the server from the specified URL and places the resulting content in the specified element.
- The [`load` *event*](http://api.jquery.com/load-event) occurs when an element and its sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event is only available on certain types of elements.

Basically, they do two completely different things (but they do have the same function name in jQuery so they are easily confused).

As for your problem of event handlers being un-bound when you load new content in, you need to use *event delegation* using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("container_selector").on("event", "child-element-selector", function () {...});
```

Comment: so - this would be separate from loading the content... for example i have a "href" tag that fires an event that is inside that dynamically loaded content. i would have to set up the event listener like this: $(".link").on("click", "a", function () {...});    ?

Comment: @waterlostinthewell: I think that would work. But you could also just use: `$(".link").live("click", function () {...});`

Comment: @andrew: That seems to solve my immediate issue. I now see how .load and on("load") differ. Seems like if i am planning to load dynamic content, my event listeners should be set with the    .on.Thanks!