# Javascript trigger for load of all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 external html pages loaded by this code:

```
<div id="header-div"></div>

<div id="footer-div"></div>
```

my js file contains this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#header-div").load("/AfekDent/header.html");
    $("#footer-div").load("/AfekDent/footer.html");
});
```

I want to run a function when specific element in the header file is created - 
what trigger can i use for it?

It's ok the trigger will occur when all elements will be loaded.

thanks!

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you'll see that the `load()` function accepts a `complete` callback that will execute when it's done loading. `$("#some-div").load("page.html",  function() { alert("Load was performed."); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a callback to your `load()` call.

```
$(function () {
    $("#header-div").load("/AfekDent/header.html", function() {
        console.log('My header was loaded!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback on the `#header-div`, which will execute the code after the entire header has loaded.

```
$("#header-div").load("AfekDent/header.html", function() {
  someFunction();
});
```

However, if you want to execute code after a *specific element in the header loads*, try something like:

```
$("#specific-element").on("load", function() {
  someOtherFunction();
});
```

If you want to learn more about the difference between `load` and `on("load")`, [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676460/load-vs-onload) or read the jQuery documentation for [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

For simplicity, I'd recommend executing code with `$(document).ready(function() {yetAnotherFunction();});`, but it depends on your specific case.