# How to load separate file with jquery now that .load is deprecated?

Tags: jquery

I want to load a php file using jQuery. My current code works great right now; however, I know that `.load` is deprecated and the `.on` event handler is often recommended instead. How do I use the `.on` event handler to load a php file?
This is my current code and it works great.

```
$("#content").load("index.php", function(){});
```

I tried replacing it with this, but no success.

```
$("#content").on("load", "index.php", function(){});
```

Comment: look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676460/load-vs-onload

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. But I still don't understand the best way to load content without ".load". Or is only the event handler "load" deprecated and I can continue using .load to load separate files?

Comment: you can use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The `load` method are deprecated because is an ambiguous signature.

> The .load() method is an ambiguous signature, it can either be an ajax
> load or attach/fire a "load" event.

But note that for **attach/fire a load** event you can use `on()` instead.

But I think your requirement is `ajax` part of load and as [s.kuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13573444/s-kuznetsov) said in comment you need to use `$.ajax()` or `$.get()` for meet your requirement.